# How to filter records on boolean field in Batch apex

Tags: apex, soql, batch, dynamic-soql

Fields are as follows:-

1. Assistantname which is text
2. Level__c is a picklist field
3. prestigious_contact__c is  a boolean field

When I run this query I keep getting Unexpected Token :-'&&' error message

Query is for Batch Apex.

```
string query='SELECT ID,Ownerid,Accountid,prestigious_contact__c from contact where assistantname=\'Christy\' && level__c=\'primary\' && prestigious_contact__c';
```

Comment: This is not valid SOQL syntax, as the error suggests. You should review the SOQL and SOSL Reference to learn the correct syntax for writing queries; see particularly [Condition Expression Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm) and the subsections under [fieldExpression Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm).

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to use an inline query. The Database.getQueryLocator(string) method should only be used when necessary, and it's apparently not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation on **[`Condition Expression Syntax (WHERE Clause)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm)**, you will see that the correct syntax is to use `AND` or `OR` to join conditions.

```
WHERE Field1__c = 'value1' AND Field2__c = 'value2' AND Field3__c = 'value3'
```